# How do I handle responses as arrays? (Facebook PHP SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to the Facebook SDK and i'm sure this is dead easy to do, however I can't seem to figure it out.

Basically after I authenticate i want to get some information from the user's profile. This works fine for things such as name or username:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo "Welcome " . $user_profile['name'];
```

this returns: "Welcome Name Lastname" which is fine, however if I try something like

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo "Welcome " . $user_profile['hometown'];
```

This returns as: "Welcome Array" instead of "Welcome Los Angeles", what I want it to do is to dispay the name of the hometown. I tried some things that I thought would work but I couldn't figure it out so if someone could point me to the right direction i'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **hometown** here is an array and it looks like:

```
[hometown] => Array
(
        [id] => 12345678
        [name] => Los Angeles, California, United States
)
```

You can access the hometown using:

```
$user_profile['hometown']['name']
```

However, in order to access the city, state and country individually, you do something like:

```
$hometown = explode(",",$me['hometown']['name']);

echo $hometown[0]; //Los Angeles
echo $hometown[1]; //California
echo $hometown[2]; //United States
```